# Access custom Cell Renderer of the TileList component AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, label, renderer, tilelist

I've implemented a custom cell renderer for the TileList component by extending the ImageCell class like this:

```
package 
{
   import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
   import fl.controls.listClasses.ImageCell;
   import fl.controls.Label;

   public class CustomImageCell extends ImageCell implements ICellRenderer
   {
      public var lblName:Label;

      public function CustomImageCell() 
      {
          lblname = new Label();
          addChild(lblName);
      }
   }
}
```

I assigned it like this:

```
tilelist.setStyle("cellRenderer", CustomImageCell);
```

now when I add items to the tilelist, how would pass some text to that label in the cell renderer?

```
tilelist.addItem({label:"Let this text go to the lblName", source:new Bitmap(bData)});
```

EDIT:

I'm doing this because I need TileList's items' label to be multiline, and I was told the only way to do that is to implement a custom Cell Renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. You have to override set data method and assign a value to your variable from there:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _data = value;
        if(_data.label) lblName.text =_data.label;
}
```